# Django get all Model Instances that are within 2 hours of timeframe

Tags: sql, django, recursion

As a Django beginner I struggle with a very basic problem: Filter a table based on the date difference of two rows.

I have the following model:

```py
class DataPoint(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and I want to extract data points that have the same UID and are all within the range of e.g. 2 hours. I could of course use something like:

```py
DataPoint.objects.filter(uid=uid, timestamp__range=[timezone.now - timedelta(2), timezone.now])
```

but that would only return everything within the same 2 hour frame from `now`, but not dynamically given the DataPoint's timestamp.

---

So this data set:

```
(1) DataPoint: 2021-03-07 12:40
(2) DataPoint: 2021-03-07 11:40
(3) DataPoint: 2021-03-07 10:50
(4) DataPoint: 2021-03-07 08:55
```

would only return (1), (2), (3) with the query above, even though (4) is still considered connected, as it's within a 2h timeframe of (3).

Been trying to get this to work with a `RECURSIVE` RAW SQL, as I thought this was the only way to do it with Django, but it's not working as expected either.

```
WITH RECURSIVE previous AS (
    SELECT id, uid_id, timestamp FROM core_datapoints
        WHERE id = %s
    UNION ALL
        SELECT s.id, s.uid_id, s.timestamp
        FROM core_datapoints s
        WHERE uid_id = s.uid_id AND (timestamp - INTERVAL '2 HOUR') <= s.timestamp
) SELECT id, timestamp FROM core_datapoints WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM previous);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `lead()` and keeping track (in reverse order) of when the first break is of more than 2 hours.  The idea is then to enumerate such breaks -- and choose the rows where there are none:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             sum(case when next_timestamp > timestamp + interval '2 hour' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by uid_id order by timestamp desc) as cnt_break
      from (select c.*,
                   lead(timestamp) over (partition by uid_id order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
            from core_datapoints c
           ) c
     ) c
where cnt_break = 0;
```

Note:   You haven't specified the database -- and date/time functions vary significantly by database.  I have based this on the code in your question and standard SQL.